# React-Slick SlickGoTo implementation not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, react-slick

I am using react-slick and I am trying to find the solution to go to initial slide on clicking the last slide

I have tried adding `afterChange`,`beforeChange` and added `slickGoto(0)` if `nextslide` is equal to `last-slide-num.Actually` nothing happens
I have gone through [this](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/slick-go-to)... but that is not sufficient

```
const settings = {
      dots: false,
      infinite: false,
      autoplay: false,
      speed: 500,
      arrows: true,
      slidesToShow:2.7,
      beforeChange:(current,next) => {
      if(current === 2){
        this.slider.slickGoTo(0);
        }
      },
}
```

This is the setting

Expected should go to initial slide

Answer (score 0):

You can use this setting

```
infinite: true
```